# Alter Text Below PayPal Option

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.0

I am trying to alter the text below the PayPal express checkout but cannot find it anywhere? Where do i start to look.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please copy your core module file into your theme from this path : `/vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/template/payment/paypal-express.html` and go to your theme's file to add text below the PayPal express checkout.

> /app/design/frontend/{VENDOR}/{THEME}/Magento_Paypal/web/template/payment/paypal-express.html

You can add any text into this file, and please run clear cache, static content deploy commands after this changes.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, on my theme path i can get to Magento_Paypal but after that the only path i have is templates/billing

Comment: i figured it out!. All sorted, thanks for your help

Comment: Please accept my ans if its usefull to you, Thanks!